# Replace specific value in all cells when selecting from SQL table to dgv

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I use a Select query to fill a DataTable from an SQL table and then use that DataTable as a DataSource for my DataGridView.

In my SQL table I have a column named 'status' that contains values between 1-3. When I display my dgv on my form I want every cell on column 'status' with value of 1 to change to "open".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your Select Query,

```
SELECT (CASE [status] WHEN 1 THEN 'Open' END) AS [status]
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [status] = 1 THEN 'Open' 
            WHEN [status] = 2 THEN 'Something else' 
            ELSE 'One more time' END AS [status]
FROM table1
```